# How to call one macro program from another in SAS Enterprise Guide?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

Is there any macro command that allows calling one program from another (the `%run_program()` pseudo code)?

Program "Settings":

```
%let myvar="HELLO WORLD!";
```

Program "Program":

```
%run_program(Settings); *Pseudo-code;
%put &myvar; *Should print *Should print "HELLO WORLD!";
```

[image: Overview]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not exact answer on your question, but if you only want to be sure that `Settings` is run before `Program` when `Run Process Flow` you can link them together.

1. Right click `Settings`,
2. choose `Link Settings to...`,
3. and pick `Program` from the dialog.
4. `Run Process FLow` And see the `Hello World` be printed in the log.

Comment: This is probably the most "enterprise guide" solution, as long as you can tolerate the intricacies of process flows.  You also can simply run the process flow _without_ linking them, and as long as they're in the proper order on the flow page (NOT the project tree, that order is irrelevant - the right side one is what matters), they'll run in the right order.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are looking for the `%include` function.

You would have to save 'Settings' as a stand-alone program on your server like '/myserver/somefolder/settings.sas'.

Then you could ensure that it is run via:

```
...some code
%include ('/myserver/somefolder/settings.sas');
... more code
```

The program would run exactly as it would if you copy-pasted the contents of 'settings.sas' into the current program.

Comment: This isn't really the Enterprise Guide Project solution, though it would work if you are using EG as if it were local base SAS.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the Process Flow, you also can create an Ordered List.  This allows you to run programs in a single process flow in multiple different orders (or run a subset of a process flow).

You create that in New -> Ordered List, then Add programs to it, move them up/down in the order you want.  Then you see the ordered list on the left in the project tree and can right click to run it (or select then F8).

There is not a macro command to run a program in enterprise guide; you can use automation via .NET if you want to do things like that.  Chris Hemedinger on [The SAS Dummy](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/) has a good [article on EG automation](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2012/04/17/doing-more-with-sas-enterprise-guide-automation/).